# copy only tables with data from one database to another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two database , `dbOne`(version - 10.50.1600 - locate in office server )  and `dbTwo`(version - 10.0.1600 - locate in my local server) .
I want to copy `dbOne`'s tables with data to `dbTwo` .
Is there any way or script to do it ? I don't want to upgrade my local server-version !

Answer (score 1):

"Import and Export Data" tool provided by SQL Server is a good tool to transfer data between two different servers.

Answer (score 0):

How about generating the database scripts like in the following artcles
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598148/Generate-insert-statements-from

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186472(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to transfer data from one server to another server using SQL linked server query, if both are in a same network. below are the steps

Copying table structures

Generate script of all tables from server1 database then excute in server2 database. using Generate Script utility

Copying table data

1. sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ] 
   [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]
   [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ] 
   [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ] 
   [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ] 
   [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]
2. Insert into databaseserver2.db1.table1(columnList)
   select columnList
   from databaseserver1.db1.table1

Answer (score 0):

Here are general steps you need to take in order for this to work

Migrating tables

1. Create scripts for tables in db1. Just right click the table and go to “Script table as -> Create to”
2. Re-order the scripts so that tables that don’t depend on any other tables are executed first
3. Execute scripts on db2

Migrating data

1. The most convenient way is to use SQL Server Import/Export wizard